# Fluent Validation - IOC Issue - Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control, fluentvalidation

I am getting an error with trying to create a generic IOC.

I have a ValidationService which will be used to validate my models:

```
public class ValidationService : IValidationService
{
    private readonly IValidatorFactory _validatorFactory;

    public ValidationService(IValidatorFactory validatorFactory)
    {
        _validatorFactory = validatorFactory;
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var validator = _validatorFactory.GetValidator<T>();
        var result = validator.Validate(entity);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I also have a factory:

```
public class NinjectValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IKernel Container;

    public NinjectValidatorFactory(IKernel container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        // errors here!!
        var x = Container.Get(validatorType) as IValidator;

        return x;
    }
}
```

I have also created by bindings via a NinjectModule:

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<IWriteRespository>().To<WriteRepository>();
    Bind<IReadRepository>().To<ReadRepository>();

    Bind<IContextFactory>().To<ContextFactory>();
    Bind<IWriteDataHelper>().To<WriteDataHelper>();

    Bind<IValidationService>().To<ValidationService>();
    Bind<IValidator<FundRecordModel>>().To<FundRecordModelValidator>();
    Bind<IValidatorFactory>().To<NinjectValidatorFactory>();
}
```

When I try to Validate:

```
public void AddFundRecord(FundRecordModel model)
{
    try
    {

        var results = _validationService.Validate(model);
```

I get an error:

> Error activating IValidator{FundRecordModel}\r\nNo matching bindings
>   are available, and the type is not self-bindable.\r\nActivation
>   path:\r\n

I have double checked everything but can't seem to find out what is wrong...

Comment: The code you have supplied is not valid. E.g. `ValidationService` calls a generic method `_validatorFactory.GetValidator<T>();` to find the *Validator* but `NinjectValidatorFactory` only defines a non generic method `CreateInstance(Type validatorType)`

Comment: Your question answered my question +1 :D